# A program that deletes itself

Tags: code-golf, file-system

If a compiled language is used, the program must delete the compiled executable (but need not delete the source file). If an interpreted language is used, the program must delete the source file.

My opening bid:

### Python (29 characters)

```
import os;os.remove(__file__)
```

Edit: to prevent solutions like [rm -rf /](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/11797/14091), the program must not delete anything except the executable or source file.

```css
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;overflow:hidden}
```

```html
 <iframe src="https://xmikee1.github.io/ppcg-leaderboard/?id=19355" width="100%" height="100%" style="border:none;">Oops, your browser is too old to view this content! Please upgrade to a newer version of your browser that supports HTML5.</iframe>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a program that deletes itself](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17327/write-a-program-that-deletes-itself)

Comment: @JanDvorak That question was stricter, requiring a .exe file. This is more lax.

Comment: Hmm... what if I vote to close in the opposite direction, then?

Comment: @JanDvorak That would be excellent! And a first, an old question closed in favour of a newer one.

Comment: Vote cast. Now let's wait and see :-)

Comment: code-golf, not [tag:popularity-contest]? Aww.

Comment: @Quincunx I don't believe in popularity contests. Real code is not first validated on its elegance, but its correctness.

Comment: Obviously relevant: http://youtu.be/Z86V_ICUCD4

Comment: @JanDvorak Okay, so prefer the trivial question where interpreted languages can do it with no problem.

Comment: @EMBLEM I think you may be on the [wrong forum](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also, I disagree that  this is a duplicate. The linked problem specifically asks for a windows executable, which is a different problem statement entirely.

Comment: you have to actually delete the file, truncating it doesn't count?

Comment: You might as well use a newline instead of a semicolon for the python answer. It's the same number of bytes and it's more readable.

Comment: May the submission be a function or does it have to be a full program?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Bash script (7 characters, 7 bytes)

```
rm "$0"
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the script file name contains spaces.

Comment: Good eye! I've updated the script to work with files with spaces in them. Only adds two more characters. Thanks!

Comment: Does this work if the file name contains double quotes?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Yes. By execution that would be e.g. `./the\"program`, `./'the"program'`, `'./tha"program'`. All works as intended. (Quotes needs to be escaped or enclosed in single quotes on call.) Would also work on files containing names with newline etc.

Comment: Bad luck with the quotation marks, gave my answer the 1 byte edge.

Comment: This tries to remove /bin/bash which is denied!

Comment: @bacchusbeale just tested on Linux Mint 17.2 64-bit and it deleted itself correctly, whether called directly à la `./scriptname`, or called like `bash scriptname`.  How did you get it to try to delete `/bin/bash` ?

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon Probably 'cause he's running `rm "$0"` in the Bash *shell* instead of in a batch *script*. You should edit the header like so: `# Bash script, 7 bytes`

Comment: @MDXF I see a variant : `rm "$0"` yields `rm: cannot remove 'bash': No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 18):

## Unix? (9):

```
#!/bin/rm
```

A classic. Uses `rm` as interpreter, for instant self-deletion. Not the very shortest though.

Comment: Or if you want to be cheaty: a 0-byte `rm` program.

Comment: The `#!` line isn't counted in score.

Comment: @Phoenix: It is if it's unusual for the language you're using; only completely standard `#!` lines that just give the name of the language's default interpreter count as zero. This is a very unusual `#!` line as far as Bash goes. (Not that this actually works in Bash, although there are other languages where it works.)

Comment: This isn't actually a Bash program (if you run it explicitly using `bash`, it won't delete anything). It's a UNIX/Linux executable. (It also works in Perl, which emulates UNIX/Linux's handling of `#!` lines so that it can be used to run shellscripts on platforms that can't do it natively.)

Comment: @Pavel Hmm... 0 bytes?

Answer (score 10):

### Batch - 6 bytes

```
Del %0
```

Pretty simple. Note: Works even if the name contains spaces.

Comment: Only if the file name doesn't have spaces.

Comment: @impinball, Sorry?

Comment: Just pointing out a little bug. If you specify DOS, it isn't, but it'll break pretty easily in Windows (ex. in Program Files). No apologies needed.

Comment: My bad...it's okay. I misremembered that quotes aren't needed in this case because they are automatically included in this.

Comment: All good. Adding tilde removes surrounding quotes. `%~0`.

Comment: I know. That's what I realized after I commented.

Comment: doesn't work if invoked without the suffix, though - "test" as opposed to "test.bat"

Answer (score 9):

## Ruby, 14 characters

```
File.delete $0
```

`$0` is a special global variable that contains the name of the currently running script.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can drop the space.

Comment: This is why I made my version of the question much more strict. Interpreted languages can do it with no problem. The idea is that a natively running application can't just pull the rug out from underneath itself

Answer (score 7):

## BASIC-80 / BASICA / GW-BASIC / IBM BASIC / Commodore 64 BASIC / Vintage BASIC / Commodore LCD BASIC / Atari BASIC *

## 5 bytes

```
1 NEW
```

Well, that's about as simple as it gets. `NEW` creates a new program, so putting this anywhere in your program will delete it.

Proof of concept on IBM BASIC (putting  `NEW` on line 40 for clarity):

[image]

<sup>* Yeah, I listed every old BASIC version I've tested this in (or pretty much ever used)</sup>

Comment: +1, There is something rather poetic about this.  Existential even.

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 17 characters

```
unlink(__FILE__);
```

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone would downvote this; it's perfectly valid. You may want to include an open tag, though `<?unlink(__FILE__);`

Comment: This PHP program prints `unlink(__FILE__);`. It does not delete the file.

Comment: @rightfold it works as described if you include an opening tag, which I would have assumed to add

Answer (score 3):

**PowerShell (32)**

```
del $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
```

Answer (score 3):

**Perl 5 (8 characters)**

```
unlink$0
```

`$0` is the script name, and `unlink` removes it. Normally, you'd at least add a space in between for readability.

Answer (score 3):

**C# (112)**

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe","/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del " + Application.ExecutablePath);
Application.Exit();
```

Shamelessly stolen from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31454/How-To-Make-Your-Application-Delete-Itself-Immedia

Answer (score 3):

#### R, 26 characters

```
unlink(sys.frame(1)$ofile)
```

Answer (score 3):

## k (8)

```
~-1!.z.f
```

Or the q equivalent for 14:

```
hdel hsym .z.f
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 18

```
open(__file__,'w')
```

Opens itsself in write-only mode, erasing itself.

Comment: This truncates the file. It does not delete it.

Answer (score 1):

## Node.js - 22 chars

```
fs.unlink(__filename);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Julia, 13 bytes

```
rm(@__FILE__)
```

Simple.  But longer. :P

Answer (score 1):

## Vitsy + bash, 8 bytes

```
iG' mr',

iG       Get the name of the use declaration at the top item (-1) (returns the current one)
  ' mr'  Concatenate "rm " to the front of it.
       , Execute via shell.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 29 bytes

```
DeleteFile@NotebookFileName[]
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 32 bytes

```
main(c,v)char**v;{remove(v[0]);}
```

Comment: Missing `}`s are allowed in C? Wow!

Comment: Nope, just a typo!  My character count included the closing `}` but I apparently copy/pasted the snippet incorrectly.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Well, since the anonymous downvoter doesn't feel like leaving a comment or retracting their vote, I have deleted my answer, which I based off of yours. You can golf this down to 29 bytes: `main(c,v)int**v;{remove(*v);}`

Comment: @MDXF I am not sure if changing `char**` to `int**` is technically valid.  I'm worried about potential alignment issues.

Comment: @Josh Well; it works... so I don't see why not. Code golf is all about using horrible methods that aren't technically valid.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 17 bytes

```
os.remove(arg[0])
```

This actually only works if you run the program by typing out the full filepath, i.e.
`lua ~/Scripts/removeself.lua` would work, but `lua removeself.lua` would not, assuming a filename of `removeself.lua` and a current working directory of `~/Scripts`.

As far as I know, there's no way to find the actual filepath of a script, just the arguments passed to it. I do know about `debug.getinfo(1).source`, but in my testing that game exactly the same results as `arg[0]`. If anyone knows of a way to find the filepath, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 13 bytes

```js
f=_=>delete f
```

---

### Try It

Logs the source of `f`, calls `f` (which deletes `f`), tries to log `f` again but throws an error because `f` is now undefined.

```js
f=_=>delete f
console.log(f)
f()
console.log(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JS, 37 bytes

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML=""
```

Does this count? It kills javascript on the page

Comment: You don't need the spaces around the `=`

Answer (score 1):

## tcl, 18

```
file delete $argv0
```

[demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_tcl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMY2M1TWNWWWQycGM) — **ATTENTION:** It is only a one time demo! Only the first time it will be runnable. Please reserve it to the question's original poster.
To try: press the `Execute` button. The green area will not report  any error. After that, any subsequent clicks on the `Execute` button will result on a `not found` error!

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, <s>69</s> 62 Bytes

Subroutine that takes no input and deletes itself.

Requires that the code below be the first line in the active code pane, and that VBA has trusted access to the VBE Project model.

```vb
Sub A:Parent.VBE.CodePanes(1).CodeModule.DeleteLines 1:End Sub
```

-2 bytes for replacing `ActiveCodePane` with with `CodePane(1)`

-5 bytes for replacing `Application` with `Parent`

Answer (score 1):

## [shortC](//github.com/aaronryank/shortC), 10 bytes

```
Aremove(*@
```

How it works:

```
A           main function
 remove(    delete file specified in next string
        *@  program name
```

Equivalent C program:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){remove(*argv);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## 8086/8088 machine code, 1 byte

```
aa    stosb
```

Assumptions:

- The registers CS, IP, ES, DI, and AL are all initially 0.
- This code is placed at address 0.

The `stosb` instruction stores the byte in the AL register at the memory location pointed to by ES and DI, then increments or decrements DI. In this case, it stores the byte 0 at the memory address 0, which happens to be where the instruction itself is.

Granted, this program doesn't delete a file or anything. But if you manage to get your hands on an 8086 processor, poke this program into memory, and run it, it will in fact overwrite itself.

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v3 - 17

```
ri $PSCommandPath
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia - 25 bytes

Write this into a file, and then include the file with `include("<filename here>")` and run `f()`:

```
f()=rm(functionloc(f)[1])
```

This is, obviously, a function - I'm not sure how one would go about detecting the file name of a file being run directly (as an include statement without a function definition in it).

Answer (score 0):

### C++, 137 bytes.

Works most of the time on windows

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string>
int main(int, char*v[]){char c[99];sprintf(c,"start cmd /C del \"%s\"/Q", *v);return system(c);}
```

### C, 90 bytes

```
void main(int n,char**v){char c[99];sprintf(c,"start cmd /C del \"%s\"/Q", *v);system(c);}
```

Comment: Most of the time?

Comment: You could save a lot of bytes by removing the unused `#include <string>`, removing extraneous spaces, and making this C, which lets you remove the `int` and `return`. Additionally, you need `#include <stdio.h>` to make this work, since that's where `sprintf` is declared.

Answer (score 0):

### MATLAB, 36 bytes

```
delete([mfilename('fullpath'),'.m'])
```

Save the above code as an m-file following Matlab's filename guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

## Nodejs, 32 bytes

```
require("fs").unlink(__filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 28 bytes

```
CREATE PROC d AS DROP PROC d
```

It just drops/removes the procedure and the code when executing itself. Usage:

```
EXECUTE d
```