# Code that will only execute once

Tags: popularity-contest, stateful

**Goal**

The goal of this challenge is to write code that will execute once and only once.  This means basically that it damages the program, script, or environment in some way.  If rebooting the system allows the code to run again that is permitted.

**Scoring**

Number of votes.  All assumptions must be clearly listed.  Any answers just initiating a reboot or halt will be disqualified.

**Additional Rules because Greg Hewgill is a demi-god**

No root access is permitted.

**End Date**

The contest will close on May 31, 2014.

**Edit**

This contest has been changed to popularity contest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A program that deletes itself](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19355/a-program-that-deletes-itself)

Comment: @PeterTaylor a possible Solution would be the a self delete but as the result are showing it isn't the only one.

Comment: Is it ok, if the programm shuts the PC down?

Comment: No restarting the computer is equivalent to halt.

Comment: I feel that this would be much more interesting as a `popularity-contest` type question. Perhaps ask it again, or a similar one. Too many simple low character count winners that are already answered in the program that deletes itself question.

Comment: this is now a popularity contest.

Comment: To a lot of people calling `vi` in a single terminal environment has this effect, no escape from it unless you reboot :) Just a joke here.

Comment: I feel like this would be much more interesting if the original script had to be able to do something useful. Using the shebang line to mangle or remove the file is a funny interpretation of the original question, but doesn't really allow executing a "script" in the popular meaning of some Turing-complete code.

Comment: The site is free for you to propose such a question.

Comment: I suspect it will be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Trapdoors!  Don't you all remember Jurassic Park (book, not movie)?

Comment: `echo "If you try to execute me again, it means you are an idiot.";` <-- Nobody will execute more than once :P

Comment: @orion You misspelled "emacs".

Comment: Would missile-related software have qualified? ;)

Comment: fork bomb? `:(){ :|: & };:`

Comment: @l0b0 see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28747/16411

Comment: `echo "This program prints gullible if it is executed again."`

Answer (score 549, accepted):

### [Vigil](https://github.com/munificent/vigil)

Finally a usecase for Vigil!

```
def main():
  raise Exception()
```

Excerpt from the "language specification":

> It goes without saying that any function that throws an exception which isn't caught is *wrong* and must be punished.
>
> ...
>
> If an oath is broken, the offending function [...] *will be duly punished.*
>
> How?
>
> **Simple: it will be deleted from your source code.**
>
> The only way to ensure your program meets its requirements to absolutely forbid code that fails to do so. With Vigil, it will do this for you *automatically.*

There are other ways to do this, because Vigil provides the keywords `implore` and `swear` which are basically oaths to adhere to certain pre- and post-conditions:

```
def main():
  swear 0 > 1
```

Comment: No doubt, this _deserves_ to win.

Comment: Finally, a sufficiently vigilant language for the modern age! I'm going to start using it in production. All bugs must be purged.

Comment: To me it seems that it is not necessarily the fault of the function that throws an uncaught exception, it could also be that the functions on the call stack are negligent for failing to catch it. It could even suggest the architecture of the whole application is flawed (Because perhaps there is no way to properly handle that exception without restructuring the code?) In short, the whole program should be deleted.

Comment: @JonathanPullano [you're not the first one to notice that](https://github.com/munificent/vigil/issues/16) ;)

Comment: Additional points for swearing. A program making a confident false statement no doubt needs to be eliminated.

Comment: Congratulation for winning and thank you for participating.

Comment: Omg this language is awesome!

Comment: Granted, it's not `code-golf`, but how about a simple `def main():x` which will `NameError`?

Comment: @NickT ah, good point. This answer was never competitive for code golf with all those 4 to 6 character answers, so I went for something simple and neat, but didn't really care about properly golfing it down. (You can see in the edit history that there was a stage where I actually said "heck, this isn't winning anyway, but I'm posting it for the fun of it" back when the challenge actually *was* code golf.)

Comment: @JonathanPullano Unless that function is `main`.

Comment: Would `main=lambda:0/0` work?

Answer (score 316):

## Pretty much any Linux distro, 9 chars

This one is a classic!

```
#!/bin/rm
```

Put this in a file and run it:

```
> ed
a
#!/bin/rm
.
wq foo
> ls
Mail mbox foo
> chmod 777 foo
> ./foo
> ls
Mail mbox
```

Aaand it's gone!

As to what is going on:
I'm really just running `rm`! `#!` is called a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). And if you put one of these followed by a path to some executable as the first line in your script, the program loader will execute your script file with whatever you wrote there - the default is usually `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` (Bourne-again shell / Bourne shell). The first argument passed to this script will be the filename itself (which is why you see so many solutions including `%0` or `$0` and the likes in here); so by making my file contain `#!/bin/rm` and running it, all I'm doing is passing the filename of my file to `rm`.

Comment: For those that don't know Linux, what does this do?

Comment: Without ever having used Linux myself, I *think* it deletes the script file.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs the `#!` sequence starts a shebang, which identifies what interpreter you are going to use for the script - normally `/bin/bash`. Here, Flonk has used `/bin/rm` as an "interpreter". `rm` is a program which deletes files. because Linux thinks that we want `rm` to be an interpreter, it passes the filename as an argument to it. therefore, the file deletes itself

Comment: @NateKerkhofs yup, professorfish is pretty much spot on. I've included a little explanation in the post aswell.

Comment: This is hysterical

Comment: -1, The question mentions no root access is permitted.

Comment: @user80551 I don't need root access for this.

Comment: @Flonk Oh, sorry, I misunderstood this and thought you were deleting `/bin/rm` itself; retracted my down-vote. EDIT: Turns out I can't retract it now unless you edit your answer.

Comment: hmm... `./foo mbox`

Comment: Not Linux specific, should pretty much work on every unixoid system.

Comment: This should even work in cygwin on Windows

Comment: @Izkata Or ./foo -rf / [My conscience leads me to warn people not to try this to see what it does.]

Comment: @yoniLavi Why? _Real_ programmers use cat :)

Comment: Of course, the really evil use would to give it a name of a commonly used command (like `less`) and put it in the path before the real one ... then the next time the affected user does `less foo.txt`, the file `foo.txt` will disappear, and since the script gets deleted as well, the victim will have no way to find out why.

Comment: @slebetman Indeed it works on Cygwin, I tested it (Windows 8 64-bit).

Comment: You can golf it to 4 bytes by removing the /bin/

Comment: @Ourous You were very correct when you posted this! +1

Comment: @celtschk But then it would need to be invoked as `./less` and not `less`.

Comment: @cat, not if it were added to the `$PATH` environment variable ahead of the real one.

Comment: @LukStorms, but then that would only work if the current working directory of the process that executes that script contains an executable file called `rm` that removes the file it is given as argument (or any other behaviour that answers the question) (like /bin on most Unix-like systems).

Comment: Technically, when you're creating that file with `ed`, you're adding a newline character, so that makes 10 chars in total. Without the newline (`printf '#!/bin/rm' > foo`), it still works on Linux or Solaris for instance, but not on FreeBSD (unless invoked from zsh which will parse the she-bang itself after the system return ENOEXEC because of the missing newline)

Comment: Strictly speaking this is an rm script, the language should be rm.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280778/why-does-the-following-script-delete-itself

Answer (score 263):

## x86 binary, 4 bytes

```
F0 0F C7 C8
```

Assumption: Must be run on a P5 Pentium CPU.

The above instruction is commonly known as the [F00F bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_F00F_bug). It attempts to execute an invalid instruction, prefixed with *lock*.

This freezes the CPU up completely (not a halt nor a reboot) and it doesn't even require root access.

Comment: Wow... that is really interesting.

Comment: Pulling the power cable and restarting won't fix it?

Comment: @JackM: It will, but that's explicitly allowed in the question.

Comment: @Dennis Seems like a little bit of an edge case, since it doesn't really prevent the script from running, it stops *anything* from running. Still an interesting submission, though.

Comment: @JackM, that seems like a great way to stop the "script" from running.

Comment: I remember when this bug was making the rounds.  A kernelside workaround was found almost immediately -- it won't crash the computer unless you're running an OS without the patch.

Comment: 200 upvotes \o/ nice answer :D

Comment: For who this is interesting? The one want to stop the PC...

Comment: @RosLuP 209 different users, apparently. If you disagree, downvote and move on.

Answer (score 158):

## Bash, 5

```
>"$0"
```

Truncates itself to zero length.

If the filename doesn't contain spaces, `>$0` works for **3 chars**!

Comment: Actually, the quotes are never needed for a variable used in a redirect filename like this, even if the program or path to the program contains spaces, due to a special case in shell parsing rules.  So you can always do it in 3 chars!

Comment: @apenwarr it says "$0: ambiguous redirect" when without quotes and the filename contains spaces

Comment: @apenwarr, it is needed if the shell that interprets that script is based on ksh88 or is bash not in posix mode. It's not about space, it's about any character of `$IFS` for bash and wildcard characters for bash and ksh88. A she-bang less script will usually be interpreted by the system's sh, but some shells including bash and ksh88 will interpret them in a child of themselves instead.

Answer (score 154):

## gzip

```
#!/bin/gzip
```

To much annoyance to people used to nondestructive commandline tools, `gzip` by default ruins the original file, replacing it with a gzipped version (adding a suffix).

This is a variation on the `#!/bin/rm` option, except this one is recoverable by manual human intervention (call `gunzip` on it). As a special bonus, the resulting file is much longer than the original (the difference depends on the filename length).

Warning: location of `gzip` may vary.

EDIT: as pointed out by WChargin, this is more portable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gzip
```

The rest of the file can have any content. It's essentially a file that, when called, hides itself in a box and refuses to come out until you forcibly unpack it.

Comment: I never thought of it before but you are absolutely correct.

Comment: very interesting

Comment: "Warning: location of `gzip` may vary" — this isn't [tag:code-golf], so you can use `#!/usr/bin/env gzip`

Comment: +1 just for `It's essentially a file that, when called, hides itself in a box and refuses to come out until you forcibly unpack it.` You made my day, and it's 1am.

Comment: _It's essentially a file that, when called, hides itself in a box and refuses to come out until you forcibly unpack it._ made me laughing. :D

Answer (score 126):

## Bash, <s>13</s> 12

Not the shortest, but it doesn't actually delete the file or make the system unusable.

```bsh
chmod 0 "$0"
```

If the filename doesn't contain spaces, you can remove the quotes to save 2 chars.

### Explanation

It removes all permissions (`rwx`) from itself. When you attempt to run it, or even view its code, a second time, without manually restoring the permissions, it will say something like

```bsh
bash: <FILENAME>: Permission denied
```

Restore the permissions with

```bsh
chmod +rwx <FILENAME>
```

### Old version

Only removes execute permissions, but one char longer (this was a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question before it got changed to [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)):

```bsh
chmod -x "$0"
```

### Sneaky version by Łukasz Niemier

```bsh
#!/bin/chmod 0
```

Comment: `chmod 0` works too

Comment: @gnibbler thnx, added

Comment: I think you can call the program `a` and save yet 3 chars: `chmod 0 a`

Comment: @tohecz that's basically cheating though

Comment: Even nicer `#!/bin/chmod 0`

Comment: Take `chmod 0 *` for 9 bytes.

Answer (score 120):

## 6800 machine code - 1 byte

```
0xDD
```

This is known as HCF or [Halt and Catch Fire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire#Motorola_6800)

Comment: Well, the rules say "Any answers just initiating a reboot or halt will be disqualified", but this doesn't *just* initiate a halt, because it also catches fire. Thus, +1!

Comment: Catch fire and no more cpu, so code will run once :))

Answer (score 100):

## Shell + sed, 16 bytes

Not quite as destructive as some of the other answers ;-)

This script inserts a comment `#` at the beginning of every line of itself:

```
sed -i s/^/#/ $0
```

Comment: How about `sed -i g $0`?

Answer (score 97):

### Commodore 64 BASIC

This one doesn't delete the program.

```
1 POKE 2048,1
```

[image: Self-destruct]

According to the [Commodore 64 memory map](http://sta.c64.org/cbm64mem.html), address`2048`is unused, but it must contain a value of `0` so that the BASIC program can be RUN.

Comment: Does poke simply move a variable to a location?

Comment: @ojblass yes, effectively.  `poke a, b` is equivalent to the C code `*((unsigned char *)a) = b;`.

Comment: I'd like to visualise my FaceBook pokes that way!

Comment: Oh wow... I remember PEEK and POKE from C64 BASIC!  I was writing this stuff around 1977.

Comment: side note: A `0` byte is used to mark the end of code lines; so address 0x800 probably needs one to mark the beginning of the first code line.

Answer (score 95):

Assumption: Running Solaris, logged in as root

```
killall
```

Comment: does solaris really have such a thing?

Comment: Yes, it does just what it says on the tin and kills *all* running processes.

Comment: one upvote for you!

Comment: i can beat you though... you ready?

Comment: alright just for you... made it harder now I am thinking too

Comment: how many characters does it take to fill the file system up?

Comment: 1, The question mentions no root access is permitted.

Comment: @user80551 he's the reason for that rule.

Comment: Don't worry, Linuxes has the command too: killall5.  It's in /sbin so only on root's path in Debuntu.

Comment: @FauxFaux `killall5` kills not all processes, only those not in current session and not kernel threads.

Answer (score 75):

## Batch: 5 Bytes

```
%0|%0
```

It is basically the forkbomb for Windows.

The app starts its first argument twice. Don't run it in a productive environment ;)

Comment: Is there a productive windows environment? (I'm joking of course).

Comment: it looks so innocent!

Comment: Yeah it does, I actually got tricked once -.-

Comment: Ok, definitely don't try that. It didn't go well.

Comment: @JimBalter thank you :D

Comment: Don't have the rep to downvote, but it violates "runs only once" in the most severe way possible.

Comment: @Xan Why? You start it once and then it crashes the computer. I know, it starts itself twice, but how does it violate the rule?

Comment: Statement: "The goal of this challenge is to write code that will execute once and only once". Your code explicitly executes itself again.

Comment: @ojblass would you please decide if it is ok or not?

Comment: I believe a human only executes it once and that it qualifies.

Comment: It doens't crash the computer instantly. I can actually run this multiple times on a windows machine before it starts to catch fire.

Comment: What did I do to my computer :(

Comment: Question: does running this actually do anything that's not fixable by a restart? The comments are worrying me.

Comment: It is a classic forkbomb, it will kill the computer and than you should restart it and all is fine.

Comment: I was hoping to find this in the answers. +1 :)

Comment: After I executed it on my PC, my second monitor stopped working! :O Windows cannot detect it, what have you done?

Comment: @Knerd Nothing happened to my computer :) My computer screen closed when I ran this forkbomb for a while, and when I opened my screen the program is still running (it did not stop); it seems that nothing has happened.

Answer (score 73):

## Python, 18

```
open(__file__,'w')
```

Truncates the file by opening it in write-only mode.

Comment: Just in case you're serious, it opens itself (`__file__` refers to its own filename). Opening in `w` mode truncates the file, basically clears it.

Comment: @Bob I thought the file was only written when you .close()'d it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I *think* the truncation happens on the open, but regardless the Python runtime should flush all open files at the end of the program, and either Python or the OS will close them when the process ends. 'course, it's generally good practice to explicitly close open handles when you're done with them.

Comment: The "right" way to handle files in Python is with... er, with. `with open("myfile.txt","r") as thefile:` and then your file-handling code will automatically close the file when you're done.

Comment: This could be shortened to something like `open("f.py","w")`.

Comment: Doesn't cease to work whrn .pyc remains

Answer (score 61):

## JavaScript

```
localStorage.x = eval(localStorage.x + localStorage.x)
```

The first time you run it, it'll run fine:

```
>>> localStorage.x = eval(localStorage.x + localStorage.x)
NaN
```

If you try to run it more (even if you refresh), you'll get an error:

```
>>> localStorage.x = eval(localStorage.x + localStorage.x)
ReferenceError: NaNNaN is not defined
```

Comment: So if you run it a lot of times, you get the Batman theme. +1 for that.

Comment: @Hankrecords Sadly, not really, since this is not gonna execute later...

Comment: @Soaku Bummer...

Comment: @Hankrecords unless you remove `eval`, but then it won't fulfill this challenge

Answer (score 49):

IBM's CMS Operating System, which is a single-user operating system which runs as a guest under IBM's VM Hypervisor, has an interesting file-structure.

Files consist of three elements, File Name, File Type, and File Mode. The File Mode consists of two elements, a single alphabetic, which for ease of explanation can be regarded in a similar way to the Drive Letter for Windows/MS-DOS, and a single numeric digit.

The single numeric digit has meaning, http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zvm.v54.dmsa3/hcsd0b10127.htm, and for this task it is the number 3 which is interesting:

> File Mode Number 3
>       File mode number 3 means that files are erased after they are read. You can use file mode number 3 if you do not want to maintain
>   copies on your minidisks or in your SFS directories.

So, spend hours writing your script and file it as `LOST FOREVER A3'. Run it, it works first time. Set off home, job well done.

Note, no message is produced indicating the erasure. After all, everyone knows what that `3` means, don't they?

It is actually of course very useful. You can, once testing is complete, use the `3` for temporary files, and not have to clean up afterwards, because they are read-once files.

Comment: The link is dead and it's not on archive.org.

Answer (score 47):

### Bash , 12

**Note: This is destructive.**

```
:(){ :|:&};:
```

It's the popular bash fork-bomb. It exponentially eats all memory and PID's locking up the system. A hard-reboot will allow the code to be run again though why would you want to do that?

---

### Bash , 10

```
:(){ :&};:
```

For two less chars, this eats your memory linearly.

---

### Bash , 7

```
w;PATH=
```

`w` is chosen as the shortest executable that I could think of.

This simply erases the path variable so the shell can't find `/usr/bin/w` the next time. Restarting the shell fixes it as the path is usually stored in `~/.profile`

Comment: Darn it :D I just had the same idea :P

Comment: `:(){ :&};:` shouldn't eat your memory. It stops as soon as it has forked, so there's only ever `O(1)` active. You've done `while(fork());`, what would eat your memory linearly is the equivalent of `fork(); while(1);`.

Comment: @marinus Open up system monitor and run it for a few minutes. Your memory usage should increase *very slowly.* The command does quit though so you can easily run it again before reaching OOM.

Comment: Wow! those are some deadly emoticions! I best not call my computer bignosed frownyface `:(){`   ....

Comment: If I remember correctly... the fork bomb periodically leaves one PID open.  The script can be run again in that interval... and if that doesn't count, it is possible to kill all the forks with some effort.  Rebooting is simply the easiest solution.

Comment: @Brilliand Of course it's possible to fight it. This also assumes that `ulimit`'s haven't been set (or anything else to prevent this in the first place).

Comment: I don't think this qualifies.  It doesn't make it impossible for the script to run again, instead it guarantees that it runs again (many times).

Comment: @BenVoigt The entire script includes defining the function. The function is just getting executed many times. Defining the function would be reasonably difficult in the short time that you have before reaching OOM.

Comment: @user80551 I suppose actively working to repair the damage without a reboot doesn't count, but I think simply trying to run the script again every few seconds until it succeeds does.

Answer (score 47):

### Commodore 64 BASIC

```
0 NEW
```

[`NEW`](http://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/NEW) deletes the program.

Comment: What's that do?

Comment: @user973810 if i remember basic, new is for cleaning memory, so it will delete program

Comment: Nice. Not specific to Commodore 64, probably works as is on almost every 8-bit BASIC machine from the 80's...

Comment: You could OLD or O. it back too. I new'd 12 months of 12 year olds game coding genius ;p  work by accident once. Then accidentally saved instead of old-ing. O. didnt work anymore :( I did learn how hex editors worked pretty sharpish though :)

Comment: @ysap: It would be more portable if it were using 1 as line number; not all BASIC implementations supported line number 0.

Comment: Also `GO64` command on Commodore 128 could apply to the contest

Comment: @MattWarren `OLD` might be C128 Basic (Commodore Basic V7.0), but the C64 (Commodore Basic V2) definitely did not have it.

Answer (score 22):

### C#

Shortest code for deleting self

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del \"" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "\""));
```

Code for making it unnoticeable in the UI

```
Process.Start( new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Arguments = "/C choice /C Y /N /D Y /T 3 & Del \"" + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location+"\"",
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden, CreateNoWindow = true, FileName = "cmd.exe"
});
```

Comment: At last, a C# answer!

Comment: Why is choice required?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I'm guessing it's used for a delay  (`/T 3`).  The caller needs to exit before the executable can be deleted.

Answer (score 21):

### My Name's Shell...PowerShell

Classic self destructing message:

```
@'
##################################
Project X is a go

Meet Eagle 1 at WP Alpha

Further comms is hereby prohibited
##################################
This message will self destruct in 
5 seconds
'@
5..1| %{$_;Sleep 1;}
"Goodbye"
rm $(.{$MyInvocation.ScriptName})
```

Comment: Explanation, please?

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ Lines till 13 are just nonsense. After that, like any other shell, PowerShell loads the running script into memory and thus it no longer needs the original script file...so it deletes itself.

Answer (score 18):

### Bash (5)

```
rm $0
```

Assuming you don't have spaces in the filename.

Comment: This is why Unix is better than Windows: rm instead of del saved you a byte.

Comment: @MadTux I prefer *nix to Unix.

Answer (score 18):

### C++ 71

The executable file "golf" is denied permission to run next time.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
system("chmod a-x golf");
return 0;
}
```

### JavaScript/HTML 137, 145 with console test

```
<script id="s"> 
function h(){
console.log(1);
var s=document.getElementById("s");
h=s.innerHTML;
h=h.replace("h","g");
s.innerHTML=h;
}
```

Comment: Can't I just refresh the page and rerun the code?

Comment: @Templar in the context of JavaScript, I think that refreshing the page counts as rebooting (maybe?)

Comment: Even if you weren't removing the script from the page, it would still only execute once. There's no point to this.

Comment: @nderscore Looks like the *function* `h` is what will only execute once. You have to actually call it from somewhere else (analogous to running a program, I guess). Say, `<button onclick="h();">`.

Comment: Bob, yes the function  h must be called from onload or another event e.g onclick.

Comment: Given that reloading the page is allowed, and your goal is only to prevent h from being executable more than once while it's already loaded, what's wrong with `function h(){h=0}`?

Comment: If you need to rearrange the `#s` element, it should be okay to just do `h=s.innerHTML=s.innerHTML.replace("h","g")`.

Comment: With `#include <sys/stat.h>` you can access the `chmod` function directly, saving quite a few bytes (`<stdlib.h>` is no longer needed, and neither is `system`).  Also, no `return` is needed.

Comment: @professorfish How do we attempt to "execute" `<script id="s">` a second time? If refreshing the page counts as rebooting, then *any* javascript will meet the requirements of "executing only once per boot".

Comment: @nmclean You could still use the debug console to execute it a second time, but this actually deletes itself

Comment: @professorfish We can only call the function again, not re-execute the script. If we're permitting code structures that execute only once as well as actual scripts, we could have just solved this with a conditional. Maybe we could say HTML with multiple script tags referencing the same src counts as multiple execution attempts, and have the script remove the container element so only the first attempt succeeds.

Comment: You should add an assumption of running on Unix environment on the C++ entry. `chmod` doesn't exist in Windows environment.

Answer (score 16):

## sh

```
#!/bin/sh
curl http://runonce.herokuapp.com/
```

Will run only once (and it shows "Hello, world!" if it runs), even if you reinstall the system, and put the script again.

---

EDIT: I figured I would release a script behind runonce as well. Nothing special, as it wasn't supposed to be released either way, but whatever.

```
<?php
$db = pg_connect("[connection information]");
$ip = isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]) ? $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

pg_query("DELETE FROM users WHERE time < now() - interval '1 day'");

$result = pg_query_params($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip = $1 LIMIT 1", array($ip));

if (!pg_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "Hello, world!\n";
    pg_query_params($db, "INSERT INTO users (ip) VALUES ($1)", array($ip));
}
```

As well as database schema

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    ip inet PRIMARY KEY,
    time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
);
CREATE INDEX ON users (time);
```

The data is stored in Heroku's database, feel free to check [their privacy policy](https://www.heroku.com/policy/privacy) if you like. I don't check the data stored in a database, it's stored purely to allow the code to execute once.

Comment: I'd argue that this will run multiple times, it just produces no output after the first.

Comment: That didn't even once show "Hello World" for me.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Perhaps you browsed to the location in the code. Browsing counts as running the code.

Comment: What if I both reinstall the system and I also change my IP?

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin: It will work again. It's not that I can reliably determine things when everything is different.

Comment: putting the logic to restrict running again counts!

Comment: Hum, Google does not know a lot about this URL. What's the point of that runonce "service"? @xfix, is it something you wrote on purpose, or some service made by heroku? In the second case I guess it's intended to be called from hosted services of some sort. Does it only remember IP between calls? What if another unrelated person/program happens to get the same IP as a previous person/program that already called runonce? Is there a way to undo the call?

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon: Yes, it remembers IPs, and there is no way to remove an IP before automatic removal. I decided to put the source code, so that you can check what it does.

Comment: @xfix Thanks, this answers my questions. Beware of security implications [ref1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634782/what-is-the-most-accurate-way-to-retrieve-a-users-correct-ip-address-in-php) [ref2 (see comment by ONOZ)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4262098/1429390) [ref3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Brion_VIBBER/Cool_Cat_incident_report). Needing Internet access and the heroku infrastructure to run code once makes a geeky overkill funny hacky way to answer the challenge anyway. :o)

Comment: What does runonce.herokuapp.com do on a request where (ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/4262098/1429390 ) `X-Forwarded-For` header, for example, is always set to  `'; DROP TABLE users;--`? Is it protected against injections attack by the use of `pg_query_params` and the array parameter? (Notice this is drifting out of topic.)

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon: `pg_query_params` pretty much protects from SQL injection. It won't be saved however, as `'; DROP TABLE users;--` is not a valid IP (`inet` only accepts IPs), and therefore if you have a fake `X-Forwarded-For` header, your visit won't be saved. I don't consider it a problem myself.

Comment: I believe that this is a violation of a standard loophole: [Outsourcing the real answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1085/46066).

Comment: @juniorRubyist Yeah, you're right. This answer was created before that loophole post existed

Comment: Well, for me it hands out HTML with "Application Error"

Answer (score 15):

## **PHP, <s>22</s> 20 chars**

```
<?=unlink(__FILE__);
```

EDIT: Removed two chars at end per comments.

Comment: This can be further simplified as: `<?unlink(__FILE__);`, the trailing `?>` is not required

Comment: You have to start with `<?=` or the start tag is not recognized.

Comment: PHP destroying itself...ha! E_NOTICE line 3048

Comment: `<?`+space is also ok. You just cannot use a letter after the short tag.

Comment: You can save one more byte by naming the file. <?=unlink("a.php");

Answer (score 15):

## [GW-BASIC](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC), 20 bytes

```
1 COLOR 3
2 SCREEN 1
```

This is a fun one. `COLOR 3` sets the foreground color to cyan. `SCREEN 1` sets the output screen to one that does not have color. Therefore, you can run the program once, but if you try to run it again:

[image: gif]

Answer (score 11):

### Bash <strike>9</strike> 8 Characters

```
nc -l 1&
```

Will only run once, because the port is blocked forever.

Comment: I think this doesn't work, because `0` is a special port (it's reserved). When I run this on my computer I can open it multiple times. Also, it's a port `< 1024`, which means it requires root access to be listened on.

Comment: `nc -l 1&` would fix the problem with `0` and be one byte shorter, since the last space is not needed.

Comment: @kasperd Thanks for the input :-)

Comment: @heinrich5991 ok - than I would need 11 chars without root access to use a Port like 9654

Comment: Care to explain why you downvoted ?

Answer (score 11):

## Ruby,14

It rewrites the source code as the name of the program.

```
IO.write $0,$0
```

Comment: And what if the program is named "IO.write $0,$0"? "Assumption: Name the program something that isn't valid code in any language."

Comment: @Brilland a ruby program should always end with `.rb` and even if its name was "IO.write $0, $0#.rb" that won't work because when writing it will include the full path.

Comment: @Mhmd a ruby program can end with anything. For example `gem` and `irb` are Ruby programs with no extension.

Comment: @bfontaine Which have shebangs. This doesn't.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Shebangs have nothing to do with the extension. `ruby foo` and `ruby foo.rb` will work the same with or without a shebang. `./foo` and `./foo.rb` (assuming they’re executable) will both fail without shebang and succeed with it (assuming correct code, etc).

Comment: @bfontaine That they *can* doesn't mean they *should*. If they have shebangs it's clear what they will run in: an extension should be used if not. (An extension should *always* be used, but it isn't as important if you have a shebang.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4: *NO*, the name of a program should not depend on what language it's implemented in.  (Except Windows)

Answer (score 11):

**NodeJS - 33 bytes**

```
require('fs').unlink(__filename);
```

Comment: Could you describe what this does for those who are unfamiliar with the language?

Comment: @KyleKanos It gets the filesystem module `fs` and the current filename `__filename` and removes that filename from the filesystem.

Comment: You can elide the semicolon because they are optional in JavaScript.

Answer (score 10):

## Batch (6 characters)

This is assuming we have permission to delete the file, and of course can be done on Windows (maybe MS-DOS as well).

```
del %0
```

Answer (score 10):

### Batch, 7 chars

**Save unsaved work before trying this.**

Assumes either a 64-bit system, or a 32-bit system with <2 GB RAM memory. Must be saved to a .bat or .cmd file before being launched, just entering it in cmd.exe won't work.

```
^ nul<^
```

It consumes a full CPU core and fills your RAM memory at a rate of several hundred megabytes per second. If you don't stop it in time (Task Manager), it will consume every byte of RAM on your computer, your entire system will freeze and you can't do anything before you forcibly shut down and restart your computer by means of cutting power or holding the power button down.

All credits go to txtechhelp on StackOverflow for this, see more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23284131/1955334

Comment: How would this be possible ? What about paging ? Process priority ?

Comment: I ran this script, nothing happened.

Comment: @Pavel I'd guess it's fixed in Windows 10 then. I cannot reproduce it on Windows 10, but it works on Windows 8.1.

Comment: "It consumes a full CPU core and fills your RAM memory at a rate of several hundred megabytes per second. If you don't stop it in time (Task Manager), it will consume every byte of RAM on your computer, your entire system will freeze and you can't do anything before you forcibly shut down and restart your computer by means of cutting power or holding the power button down." Sounds like a horror story for computers...

Answer (score 9):

## Sinclair BASIC

```basic
10 POKE 23635,255
```

Moves the address of the BASIC program in memory away from where it should be (203) so the wrong data is found by the interpreter.

Answer (score 8):

## x86_64 NASM Assembly for Linux

This assembly program replaces itself with its source code.  It essentially "decompiles" itself, replacing the binary.

```
SECTION .data
    source incbin __FILE__
    len equ $ - source

SECTION .text
global _start

_start:

    pop rdi           ;number of parameters
    pop rdi           ;path to executable, parameter of unlink and open

    mov    rax, 87    ;unlink
    syscall
    cmp    rax, 0
    jl     error

    mov    rax, 2     ;open
    mov    rsi, 0101o ;O_WRONLY O_CREAT
    mov    rdx, 0600o ;permissions on created file
    syscall
    cmp    rax, 0
    jl     error
    mov    rdi, rax   ;file (return value of open)

    mov    rax, 1     ;write
    mov    rsi, source
    mov    rdx, len
    syscall
    cmp    rax, 0
    jl     error

    mov    rax, 60    ;exit
    mov    rdi, 0     ;return code
    syscall

    error:
        mov    rax, 60
        mov    rdi, 1
        syscall
```

Compile with:

```
nasm -f elf64 FILENAME
ld -m elf_x86_64 FILENAME.o -o FILENAME
```

Or the same thing in C (with inline assembly):

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern char src;
asm("src: .incbin \"" __FILE__ "\"\n.byte 0");

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    unlink(argv[0]);
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[0], "w");
    fprintf(file, "%s",&src);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

When run, the program deletes itself, and then writes its source code to the same path as the executable was at.  That way, the deleted file can always be retrieved by recompiling, even if you lost the original source code.

There must be a better way to do this in C (or maybe not), but I don't know any.

Isn't that much better than just having it delete itself!

Comment: Funny way to *not* answer the challenge. +1 for hack value.

Comment: The C version is not 64-bit specific or even architecture-specific, is it? So it is actually portable (x86 vs MIPS, ARM etc, Linux vs other OS even Windows), isn't it ?

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon I think so, though I haven't tried it on anything by x86_64 linux.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a couple. Unlike many, these are not destructive, just creative and unorthodox.

## Bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read <<< ''
printf "$REPLY" > "$0"
```

This one's pretty simple. The variable `$REPLY` is created implicitly by `read`, but filled with an empty herestring. That empty string is then `printf`'ed into the current script. It is a rather obfuscated equivalent of the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat <<< '' > "$0" # probably a lot more portable
```

## Windows Batch

```
copy con %0 < nul
```

The second one basically copies the console input, read from `nul`, into the current file.

Comment: Posted after this became a popularity contest

Comment: The first one won't work without root permissions. Why are you trying to replace the null device? When run as root, this would actually make the system behave erratically. You are also overwriting the null while writing into it :) Why not just move it anywhere else? Such as mv "$0" "${0}x" or something? It should do the trick.

Comment: Does the file still exist afterwards?

Comment: I now completely changed the Bash example.

Comment: How are these not destructive?

Comment: They aren't cases of the classic fork-bomb, permanently blocking a port, running `killall` on Solaris (which also kills the kernel), etc.

Answer (score 6):

## Minecraft Command Block

```
setblock ~ ~ ~ air
```

When you run this in a command block, it destroys itself.

Answer (score 5):

## x86 Machine Code (5 bytes)

HEX:

```
EA0000FFFF
```

ASM:

```
JMP FFFF:0000
```

You can try with `debug.exe`:

```
C:\>debug
-a 100
0AE7:0100 jmp ffff:0000
0AE7:0105
-g=100
```

**Explanation:** `BIOS`is always at `FFFF:0000` in memory. So this sequence boots the computer, if this is run in a protected command prompt in Windows it makes that process unresponsive.

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation for those not that familiar with machine code?

Answer (score 5):

**SQL**

```
create proc P as drop proc P
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e345/1)

Answer (score 5):

## Error safe termination (Python 2/3)

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
@contextmanager
def suicide():
    try:    yield
    finally:
        open(__file__    , 'w')
        open(__file__+'c', 'w')

#-------------------------------------
# Error safe code ;)
#-------------------------------------
with suicide():
    print("Goodbye cruel world!")
    jump_off_building_______crash
```

Comment: I like how this "suicides".

Answer (score 5):

### ARM Linux full standalone ELF, <s>50</s> <s>46</s> 45 bytes

```
7f 45 4c 46 01 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
02 00 28 00 21 00 01 00  21 00 01 00 04 00 00 00
01 98 0a 27 00 df 01 27  00 df 20 00 01
```

Adapted version of the code used in [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](https://www.muppetlabs.com/%7Ebreadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).

Assembler source (with raw encoded ELF header and comments, most of which are the same as in the article)

```armasm
@ Adaptation of
@    https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html
@ for an ARM binary which deletes itself. XD
@ $ arm-none-eabi-as -march=armv4t -mthumb runonce-arm.s -o runonce-arm.o
@ $ arm-none-eabi-ld -Ttext 0x00010000 runonce-arm.o -o runonce-arm.elf
@ $ arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary runonce-arm.elf runonce-arm

        .text              @ A lie.
        .arch   armv4t     @ Set architecture version
        .thumb             @ Needs to be Thumb to fit. ARM is too thicc.
        .syntax unified
        .org    0          @ Start at offset 0
Elf32_Ehdr:
        .byte   0x7F,'E','L','F'            @ e_ident
Elf32_Phdr:
        .word   1                                           @ p_type
        .word   0                                           @ p_offset
        .word   0x00010000 @ same as -Ttext                 @ p_vaddr
        .short  2          @ ET_EXEC        @ e_type        @ p_paddr
        .short  40         @ EM_ARM         @ e_machine
        .word   _start                      @ e_version     @ p_filesz
        .word   _start                      @ e_entry       @ p_memsz
        .word   4          @ Elf32_Phdr     @ e_phoff       @ p_flags

        @ Here is some space to put our code in.
        .thumb_func
        .globl _start
 _start:
        @ r0 = argv[0] from _start state
        ldr     r0, [sp, #4]                @ e_shoff       @ p_align
        @ unlink(argv[0])
        movs    r7, #0x0a  @ unlink
        svc     #0         @ syscall        @ e_flags
        @ exit(dontcare)
        movs    r7, #0x01  @ exit
        svc     #0         @ syscall        @ e_ehsize
        @ unreachable

        @ finish the header
        .short  0x20                        @ e_phentsize
        .byte   1                           @ e_phnum
        @ Truncated header because for some reason, Linux accepts this.
```

Basically, I took this program:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unlink(argv[0]);
}
```

Or if it is easier to read,

```c
main(c,v)int*v;{unlink(*v);}
```

And squeezed it into an ELF header using the method in that article, so it is 45 bytes with no dependencies on libc.

Works every time except when it is called from `$PATH`.

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>15</s> 14

Put this line to a file (`del.rb`):

```
File.delete $0
```

then run it (self-destructive) :
`ruby del.rb del.rb`

Comment: you can save 1 character by using :`File.delete $0`

Answer (score 4):

## PHP - 23

```
<?=fopen(__FILE__,'w');
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to drop the semicolon here. I know it's possible with short tags like this: `<?= $var ?>`.

Comment: @naiply: No. `?>` implies semicolon (you can even get a syntax error mentioning `;`), but end of document doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

## Coffescript

`_=->_=1`

compiles to:

```
var _;

_ = function() {
  return _ = 1;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

## (noncompetitive)

```
ɟ`html”Ĭ)
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=false&input=&code=%C9%9F%60html%E2%80%9D%C4%AC%29)</kbd>

Translates to `$('html').remove()` in Javascript.

Comment: What if my HTML page has no `<html>` element?

Comment: ESMin runs in the online interpreter, so that shouldn't be a problem

Answer (score 4):

## R, 7 Bytes

```
`=`=`$`
```

The code makes the "=" (used for assigning) become the "$" (used for subseting).
After that it gives error.

Comment: I don't think this is valid. If I put it in a file I can run it as many times as I want, right?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit, no on repeat execution this throws the error ``Error in `=` = `$` : object of type 'special' is not subsettable`` as validated in R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash: 4 chars

```
rm a
```

Put this in a file named **a** and run it on your Linux machine.

Comment: `rm *`  will work for every filename

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin It's better to stick to non-destructive scripts

Comment: rm $0 will also work for all filenames, at the cost of one character.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin So will `rm -rf / --no-preserve-root`, but better ;)

Comment: @fNek No, it won't. Only for those without a whitespace in their name.

Comment: @glglgl Good point.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin `rm *` will remove every file within the directory the source code is in. `rm "$0"` is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Plain TeX - 31 (24) chars

```
\openout1=\jobname\write1{}\bye
```

If you save it as file `a.tex` then:

```
\openout1=a\write1{}\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

## Bash

This deletes the file and makes sure that you can't recover it. So it definitely can't execute more than once.

```bsh
shred "$0"
```

`shred` is a program to securely delete files by overwriting them. It's in coreutils.

Answer (score 3):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM) (non-competing because it is too late)

```
f←⎕EX'f'∘⊣
```

`f` can only be called once. It needs an argument, which is ignored:

```
      f←⎕EX'f'∘⊣
      f 'dummy argument'
      f 'dummy argument'
VALUE ERROR
      f'dummy argument'
     ∧
```

It is a so-called "atop", which is a train of two functions. The left one is applied on the result of the right one.

The right function is `'f'∘⊣` which replaces any given argument with the string `'f'`.

The left function is `⎕EX`, which EXpunges the object named in its argument.

The first time around, `'f'∘⊣` returns `'f'`, which causes `⎕EX` to erase `f`. The second time around, calling `f` results in an error because `f` does not exist.

---

Here is one that can be [tried online](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7Bf%u2218%u2190%A8%7D%20%u22C4%20f%20%27dummy%27%20%u22C4%20f%20%27dummy%27&run):

```
f←{f∘←¨}
```

After [defining the function](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7Bf%u2218%u2190%A8%7D&run), the first time that [it is called](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%204&run) (with a dummy argument), e.g. `f 4`, the function ignores the argument, and instead redefines itself to be an operator (higher-order function). Now, operators need at least a left operand so when [it is called again](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%204&run), the call will fail with a syntax error.

Comment: Who said "too late" means "non-competitive"?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος [Mama Fun Roll](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/69488/43319). But you did make me take a look at what I had written, and I found a typo. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/), 39 bytes

```
FileDelete %A_ScriptDir%\%A_ScriptName%
```

(Yes, I'm aware this is an ancient thread)

Answer (score 3):

## Linux, 8 bytes

```
killall5
```

Similar to [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28675/61563), but this works on pretty much any Linux since System V and you don't need to be root. Don't believe me? Try it out on your Linux system! You'll want to save any work first...

I actually found this by accident when I was 11 messing around with Linux for the first time.

Links: [killall5 manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/killall5), [recording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B671h9AqqI7ZYzJMZWJSQnlIMFE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3):

## Commodore 64 BASIC, 7 bytes

```
POKE 1,3
```

I've had a lot of fun in various BASIC dialects `POKE`-ing around in the first few memory storage locations. Here's the effect of this one:

[image: poke 1,3]

[Try it online!](http://www.c64js.com/) You'll have to type it in yourself.

Some other `POKE`s:

- `POKE 1,1` will freeze the system.
- `POKE 1,2` will clear the screen.
- `POKE 1,4` *completely kills* the system - the power button won't even work.
- `POKE 1,5` through `POKE 1,9` do the same as `POKE 1,4`, but with varying levels of destruction.

Answer (score 3):

## TIS-100, 6 bytes

```
@0
HCF
```

The HCF (or halt and catch fire) command instantly crashes the TIS-100. The only way to run it again is to start it up again.

Comment: Invalid, I'm afraid. From the challenge: "Any answers just initiating a reboot or halt will be disqualified."

Answer (score 3):

## R16K1S60 Assembly

```
mov [ax], ax
```

Simply overrides itself with with the contents of AX. the mov instruction is only one word large, so it deletes itself. Depends on AX being 0 (most releases guarentee this)

### Safe version

```
mov [0], ax
```

Depends on ax not being this specific instruction

Comment: Woah, I never thought I'd see this language here.

Comment: @12Me21 Never say that around PPCG. Ever. We use everything ;)

Comment: I wonder if LBPHacker will ever release the new computer he made. I'm guessing he's either really busy or he's just started over. Anyway, it might be better to use `mov [0], ax` since it doesn't rely on ax being 0.

Comment: @12Me21 I can confirm he hasn't started over. He's just busy.
Also, join #powder on freenode.

Comment: I believe the instruction pointer actually points to the *next* memory cell, not the current one.

Comment: This reminds me of a bug in the assembler where you can't have multiple 0 literals even though it technically works. (for example, `mov [0],0` can be represented by 0x3000)

Answer (score 3):

## Wolfram Language (Mathematica): 37 Characters

```
Export[#,""]&/@FileNames[All,"C:/",∞]
```

Never tested this fully, but it should overwrite every single file on a Windows computer, including the Mathematica installation and the file the program is saved in by replacing all data with an empty string. Actually useful for quickly clearing out a folder, but most definitely not something I want to run.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell - 80 bytes

Pre base-4.6.0.0 : May not work on Windows. This depends on how the program is invoked.

```
import System.Environment
import System.Directory
main=getProgName>>=removeFile
```

Post base-4.6.0.0 : A bit longer but always works.

```
import System.Environment
import System.Directory
main=getExecutablePath>>=removeFile
```

Comment: It's now a popularity contest.

Answer (score 2):

**Shell script (Linux Bash); 4 characters**

```
rm *
```

*Warning ! Don’t try this at home.*

This shell script can be run only once. When run, this shell script will self-destruct.

Comment: For non-bash users: `*` is a glob, which expands to a list of all the files in the current directory. so it will delete everything in the folder the script is in as well as itself

Comment: This implicitly assumes that the process' "current directory" matches the script directory. The "run once" property will fail in other cases. Example: say script is in `~/a`, current directory is `~/b`. The script can be run with `../a/thescript` and it will only try to delete in `~/b` which won't delete the script (it's not in that directory). `b` may even be already empty before the script runs.

Answer (score 2):

**JAVASCRIPT** (<del>35</del> 26 bytes when minified, in case that matters.)
I know this is a late entry, but I had a situation where I considered being able to kill a function and decided it'd make a good entry here. (Still not sure if I'll actually use it.)

```
funny = function(){
  alert(0);
  window.funny = '';
};

funny();
funny();
```

*minified*

```
a=function(){alert(0);window.a=""};
```

*Alert isn't really needed*

```
a=function(){window.a=""};
```

Comment: Just do `function a(){a=0}`

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2.7

```
import inspect
import os
for x in range(0, 2):
    os.remove(inspect.stack()[0][1])
    print "am I dead yet?"
```

It only runs 1/2 of a time.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 56 chars

```
x[9];main(c,v)int**v;{sprintf(x,"rm %s",*v);system(x);}
```

Run on a UNIX system.  By convention, the first string param passed to a C program is the executable name.  This program simply deletes the executable (but leaves the source, which you have to recompile to run it again).

Comment: [54 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5ySmpaZl6pQXFlckpqrUFCUmVeS9r8i2jLWttrI0MjU0Nyg1jo3MTNPI1mnTBMoqaVVZl0NUa1RXFKUnFiiUaGjVaapaV37/z8A "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: why not just `unlink(*v)` or `remove(*v)` ?

Answer (score 2):

### oldschool DOS

---

You don't even need a compiler or interpreter, just the prompt. Not even reboot will let it run again once it completes (note: do not try on something you don't want to sacrifice. OS likely won't boot either.)

```
deltree C:\
```

Answer (score 2):

### Windows batch, 4 bytes

```
.>%0
```

This will attempt to execute '.' as a command, while redirecting stdout to the original file, resulting in destruction of the original file.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu), 49 bytes

```
when gf clicked
wait until<(n)<(1
change[n v]by(2
```

Assuming `n=0`, which is the initial state of a variable when it is created.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 24

Name the file `'q'`

```
import os
os.remove("q")
```

Comment: try `os.remove(__file__)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell (37)

Save following code to a script file (test.ps1)

```
rm $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

Run from command line:

PS > .\test.ps1

Script will automatically delete itself.

Answer (score 1):

**AppleScript ; 17 chars**

`delete document 1`

I was playing with more elegant solutions like this one :

`set the contents of the front document to ""`

But the action of `delete document 1` is even more fun !

Comment: you know `the` is optional? so you can just write `set contents of front document to ""`

Answer (score 1):

## [beeswax](https://github.com/m-lohmann/BeeswaxEsolang.jl), 12 bytes

```
_8F+++P]f1Fw
```

Save this program under the name `!` and execute it.

```
              lstack                       gstack
_             [0,0,0]•                                          create bee
 8            [0,0,8]•                                          lstack 1st=8
  F           [8,8,8]•                                          all lstack=lstack 1st
   +++        [8,8,16]•                                         1st=1st+2nd
              [8,8,24]•                                         3 times
              [8,8,32]•
      P       [8,8,33]•                                         increment 1st
       ]      [8,8,2377900603251621888]•                        rotate bits of 1st by 2nd steps
        f                               [2377900603251621888]•  push lstack 1st ont gstack
         1    [8,8,1]•                                          lstack 1st=1
          F   [1,1,1]•                                          all lstack=lstack 1st
           w            write gstack to file. lstack 1st=bytes used for file name, lstack 2nd= used file content bytes.
```

If we look at the stack contents in hex, it gets clearer what’s happening:

`lstack[8,8,33]•` is
`lstack[0x0000000000000008,0x000000000000008,0x0000000000000021]•` in hex.

If we rotate the bits of the 1st lstack value by 8 to the right, we get

`lstack[8,8,2377900603251621888]•`, which is

`lstack[0x0000000000000008,0x000000000000008,0x2100000000000000]•` in hex.

Instruction `f` pushes the 1st lstack value on the gstack:

`gstack[0x2100000000000000]•`

Now comes instruction w:
First, the 4-byte words of the gstack get reinterpreted as a stack of UInt8 values:

`[0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x21]•`, in little endian order. The MSB is on top of the stack.

Instruction `w` takes the 1st lstack value as number of bytes taken for the file name, and the 2nd lstack value gives the number of bytes stored in the file. `lstack[1,1,1]•` means that 1 byte is taken as file name. `0x21` is the ASCII code for `!`, which is the name of the program itself. The next single byte (lstack 2nd), the value `0x00` is stored as file content, which is not executable as beeswax program.

Answer (score 1):

### [**Caché ObjectScript**](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20161/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCOS), 12 bytes

```
k ^rOBJ($zn)
```

Output:

```
SAMPLES>do ^test

SAMPLES>do ^test

DO ^test
^
<NOROUTINE> *test
```

Answer (score 1):

## q (14 bytes)

This program deletes itself when run.

```
hdel hsym .z.f
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Bash (7 characters)

```
TMOUT=1
```

It destroying the user session within a second by terminating the shell. See: [man bash](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

Example:

```
$ TMOUT=1
timed out waiting for input: auto-logout
Saving session...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: That's not really different from typing `exit` or `^D`. The later key combination will send EOF to the shell making it 0 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## 8602/8610 machine code, 4 bytes

assuming that the program is stored at address $0800

```
78 4C 00 08
```

breakdown to assembler:

```
START    sei        // disable interupts
         jmp START  // endless loop
```

## C64 machine code, 3 bytes

```
4C E2 FC
```

this jumps to the builtin reset routine of the C64 (which, among other actions, clears the RAM)

run with `SYS <address>`

Comment: This should be two different answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [OSI Challenger 1P](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohio_Scientific)

```
POKE 3,3
```

There are lots of BASIC answers because BASIC made the mistake of allowing users to directly access all memory. But this is the shortest `POKE` command yet. If only it was [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)...

You can try this [here](http://www.pcjs.org/devices/c1p/machine/8kb/large/machine.xml) - scroll down, hit Run, hit <kbd>C</kbd> to cold-boot, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to get into BASIC mode. Then type `POKE 3,3` and watch the PC burn.

Answer (score 1):

## Braingolf Inline Interpreter, 28 bytes [non-competing]

```
'''
open(__file__,'w')
a='''
```

Braingolf's Inline Interpreter treats the braingolf code as simply a multiline string within the Python3 interpreter.

This allows what is effectively an injection attack, where you can end the multiline string with three single quotes, then insert python code. The code will only run if you then begin a new multiline quote at the end, however.

Comment: You don't have to add non-competing (that rule was removed).

Comment: Also, doesn't this wipe the interpreter file, and not the program file?

Answer (score 1):

## MOO, 24 bytes

```
delete_verb(this, verb);
```

Requires that this code is run as an actual verb, rather than through `eval` (or `$code_utils:eval_d`).

Answer (score 1):

## JS, 8B

```
a=b=>a=0
```

calling `a` means `a=0`, thus `a` can't be called 2×.

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC

```
@memory_leak
If shift("this") then @memory_leak
```

There is a bug where using `POP()` or `SHIFT()` on a string literal causes a memory leak, and eventually there will not be enough memory left for the program to run. Trying to run it again will cause an error before the program starts.

`IF ... THEN @LABEL` is a shortcut for `IF ... THEN GOTO @LABEL`.

Comment: Oh cool to see that its `If ... Then @Label` in SmileBASIC  - it is `If ... GoTo Label` In the VB family

Comment: SmileBASIC actually supports both forms, for some reason. (I think I had forgotten about it when I wrote this answer)

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 41 bytes

This script file overwrites itself with an empty string. Tested in `mawk` and `gawk`. Be aware that this only work in shell environments where the `_` variable is defined.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{print"">ENVIRON["_"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 9 bytes in console

```js
const a=0
```

throws an 'identifier already declared error' when run again

Comment: this is in the JavaScript console REPL, right? If so, you'll need to specify that.

Comment: `let` saves two bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Minecraft Function

```
datapack disable "file/pack"
```

Must be run as a function in a data pack named `pack`. Disables the data pack, thus making it impossible to run the function without re-enabling it.

Output from running `/function pack:function` twice:
[image: Executed 1 command(s) from function 'pack:function]

Answer (score 0):

## Bash: 2 chars

```
>a
```

Using inspiration from a couple of the other solutions, I came up with this solution in only two chars. Put this in a script called `a` and run it.

Just like the posts I got inspired by, this relies on the calling shell working around the missing `#!` line. Relying on this workaround is absolutely necessary, since you can't even produce a valid `#!` line in that space.

This happens if you let the kernel call it without a shell to work around the missing `#!` line:

```
$ strace ./a
execve("./a", ["./a"], [/* 47 vars */]) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
```

Comment: This script does nothing when I run it. I can run it several times.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Make sure you run it from the directory where it is located. The contents of the script will be gone after the first run, there won't be anything left to run the second time around.

Comment: The second run shows nothing, like the first run, so I did not see what happened. In fact, the first run erases the script's content. How is this achieved ?

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco `>` redirects the output of the command on that line to a file. The file name to redirect the output to is `a`. So the script runs an empty command, and the output of that empty command is written to the file `a`, which is the script itself.

Comment: OK, it is simple in fact !

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco It is easier to fit something simple into two bytes than to fit something complicated into two bytes.

Answer (score 0):

### AutoIt - 27 bytes

Truncs itself to 0:

```
FileOpen(@ScriptFullPath,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Batch (This isn't code golf)

```
echo "">%0.bat
```

Assumes you call it without the extension. If you are calling it with the extension, use `echo "">%0`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vitsy](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy), 8 bytes (I know it isn't Golf but I like to be concise)

```
iG" mr",
iG        Push name of self.
  " mr"   Push "rm " in front of it.
       ,  Execute as shell.
```

This assumes you run on a computer with `rm` as a command for delete. For an environment with `del` as its command for delete, it's 9 bytes (I think, I can't really test it):

```
iG" led",
iG        Push name of self.
  " led"  Push "del " in front of it.
        , Execute as shell.
```

It basically just deletes itself. :P

Answer (score 0):

## Z80 ASM on TI-83/84 series

```
AsmPrgm
C3FFFF
```

If you put this into a TI-83 or 84 (any version, except 84+CE and CSE), the calculator will completely reset itself. Everything in RAM will be reset, including the program at hand.

For the TI84+CSE:

```
Asm84CPrgm
C3FFFF
```

Disclaimer: This might not work if you are running any apps that change the functionality of your calculator significantly. (i.e. libraries, non-official OS's)

Answer (score -1):

## tcl, 7 bytes

```
vwait v
```

[Explanation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/vwait.htm)

Comment: The same answer I gave on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105812/29325

Comment: @ojblass: why the downvote?

Answer (score -3):

**Bash file linux**

```
#!/bin/bash
shutdown -h now
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I do believe that `shutdown` requires root access (It does when I test it) which is forbidden by the challenge.

Comment: On some/many distros it does NOT require root, any LOCAL user can run shutdown(8).